# Rest API changing body parameters conditionally

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

I have a API post method in my react app. I need to add or remove a parameter inside the body conditionally

If the variable 'locale' value is 'all'.I don't need locale inside body of post method. If the 'locale' is not 'all' then I need to attach locale inside the post method.

I used if else..just wanted to know if there is a better way to handle this.
This is just a overview (pseudo code) of my code.

```
If(locale?.includes('all')) {
return API.post(),{
body: {
id,
status
}}}
else{
return API.post(),{
body: {
id,
status,
locale
}}}
```

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation.

Comment: Note how the answers use a variable to store the body and manipulate it rather than doing everything in-line. This is a common technique when doing complex actions. Don't do too much all in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below.
I prefer to write code like this .

```
let body = {
id : id,
status : status
}

if(locale!=="all"){
body = {
...body,
locale:locale
}
return API.post(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this.

```
let body = { id, status };

if(!locale?.includes("all")){
  body = { ...body, locale };
}

return API.post(body);
```